# System could not allocate the required space in a registry log

Tags: windows-8.1, system-reserved-partition

I'm getting an error `System could not allocate the required space in a registry log` while installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on a Windows 8.1 machine.

I checked hard disk space and it's more than enough, and I run CCleaner just in case but it doesn't help.

What should I do, is there a way to cleanup the system partition somehow? The recommended action I found online is "delete unneeded files from the system partition and then retry the operation" but I'm not sure how exactly can I do that.

[screenhot: VS installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evc3J.png)

[screenshot: disk space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNScM.png)